# Angular 4 i18n get translation for TS/JS code also

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular2-aot

I'm using the default i18n process for my Angular 4 project, so I use `ng-i18n` to generate the `.xlf` without problem.

But on my typescript code I also have some texts that need to be translated and retrieved by id for the current language.

I can't find any way to do that in Angular 4. Did I miss something ? 
I'm using AOT if that matter.

The problem can also occur if the server send back some message/error code from web services, how translate them with Angular

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE for Angular version >= 11**

Since Angular version 11 we can use the built-in i18n functionality to translate strings in our code.
With '$localize' we can tag the message string to be translated in our '.TS' files like this:

`$localize 'string_to_translate';`

For further information check out the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-common-prepare#mark-text-in-component-code).

**OLD (Angular version < 11)**

Currently it is not yet possible to translate with i18n from the typescript code.

> "Angular only supports using i18n in your templates for now, I'm working on the feature that will allow you to use it in your code, but it's still a work in progress. This lib works both in code and templates" (Olivier Combe, Angular Core Team contractor)

Look at this discussion: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/495